# Windows store app - item background color's

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I cant change background color of item in my split application. I don't know, how, becaause i already tryed using css, and without any success.

This is template for item(pretty much default):

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <div class="item-info">
            <h3 class="item-title win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h3>
            <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
            <h4 class="item-description" data-win-bind="textContent: description"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css attempt:

```
.item {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image]

Also, I wish to change this violet color, and light gray color around violet(hover?) into something else.

Comment: Can you add all the classes that is used in the HTML code. This will help to find the problem.

Comment: for the background colour you can just use `background:#xxxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question to change the violet color:

Are you using your template for a ListView? I use this in my application to override the default CSS. **Note:** This will change all the ListViews in your applications.

```
.win-selectionhint,
.win-listview:not(.win-selectionstylefilled) .win-container.win-selected:hover .win-selectionborder,
.win-listview:not(.win-selectionstylefilled) .win-selectioncheckmarkbackground,
.win-listview:not(.win-selectionstylefilled) .win-container.win-selected:hover .win-selectioncheckmarkbackground,
.win-listview.win-rtl:not(.win-selectionstylefilled) .win-container.win-selected:hover .win-selectioncheckmarkbackground,
.win-listview.win-rtl:not(.win-selectionstylefilled) .win-selectioncheckmarkbackground,
:not(.win-selectionstylefilled).win-listview .win-selectioncheckmarkbackground,
:not(.win-selectionstylefilled).win-listview .win-selected.win-container .win-selectionborder {
   border-color: transparent; /* <----- COLOR HERE. */
}
```

This will remove the color around the selected list item and also remove the hovering color on selected items.

Comment: I tryed to paste this code, but it's still the same...same color's

Comment: Are you using a ListView @Klemzy? And regarding to your main-question about the red background, you should provide more code so it's easier to help you. Do you have a target div for rendering? This is bad thing to do but try this in your css: `.win-template { background-color: red !important; }` and see if you get the whole item red.

Comment: Yes I use listview. As i sayd, i use default split example from studio himself and there i'm unable to change this violet color.

Comment: Ok, great. I used this sample and now it works:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Theme-roller-sample-64b679f2

only think that i need is to change that gray color of hovered element.

Comment: @Klemzy try to add this in your css file: `.win-listview .win-container:hover {
    outline: transparent;
}`